# Sugerencia de etiqueta: Emulación

Tags: característica-nueva, etiquetas

Echo en falta la etiqueta [emulación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emulaci%c3%b3n) al escribir preguntas sobre Android. Supongo que para otras plataformas también puede ser útil.

Comment: Si a la hora de hacer una pregunta la necesitas, hazla sin la etiqueta y despues pulsa en reportar > Necesita la intervencion de un moderador  y explica que necesitas esa etiqueta. Un saludo

Comment: O dinos directamente en qué pregunta la añadirías, así la ponemos (si es pertinente) y ya la podrás utilizar en adelante.

Comment: Y puedes editar esta pregunta para añadir el texto que le pondrías a la descripción de etiqueta e info al respecto. Un saludo

Comment: Ok! Muchas gracias!